# Play: add a global optional GET parameter to all routes

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Play 2.0 framework that is working well and I want to be able to add a specific get parameter (known only by be) to all routes. That parameters should be ignore by routes.

I explain.
Suppose I have routes like :

```
GET     /add/:id              controllers.MyController.add(id : Int)
GET     /remove/:id           controllers.MyController.remove(id : Int)
```

What I want is, for example, that http://mydomain.com/add/77**?mySecretParam=ok** still goes to *controllers.MyController.add(id : Int)* and then I could get mySecretParam in request object. And the same for **all** my routes.

Do you have any idea how can I do ?

Thanks.
Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._

object Application extends Controller {

  def mySecretParam(implicit request: Request[_]): Option[String] = {
    val theForm = Form(of("mySecretParam" -> nonEmptyText))
    val boundForm = theForm.bindFromRequest
    if(!boundForm.hasErrors) 
      Option(boundForm.get)
    else
      None
  }

  def index = Action { implicit request=>
   Ok(views.html.index(mySecretParam.getOrElse("the default")))  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's Java:

Your route

```
GET     /hello/:id      controllers.Application.hello(id: Int)
```

in Application controller

```
public static Result hello(int id){
        //Retrieves the current HTTP context, for the current thread.
        Context ctx = Context.current(); 
        //Returns the current request.
        Request req = ctx.request();    
        //you can get this specific key or e.g. Collection<String[]>
        String[] param = req.queryString().get("mySecretParam"); 
        System.out.println("[mySecretParam] " + param[0]);
        //[req uri] /hello/123?mySecretParam=ok
        System.out.println("[Request URI] "+req.uri().toString()); 
        System.out.println("[Hello-ID]: " + id); //the function parameter in controller
        return ok("[Hello-ID]: " + id + "\n[mySecretParam] " + param[0]);
    }
```

Your console output

```
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
[Request] GET /hello/123?mySecretParam=imhereyee
[mySecretParam] imhereyee
[Request URI] /hello/123?mySecretParam=imhereyee
[Hello-ID]: 123
```

The key to your question is `Context` object and `Request` object from that